# how to create multiple vms in azure resourcemanager portal with same NIC using powershell

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to create multiple vms in azure resourcemanager portal with same NIC using powershell. But single VM alone getting created. when I use array for this exception occurs.

```
$i = 1;
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$vmArray1=@()
Do 
{ 
$i; 
switch($i){
{$vmName="Namenode"+$i}
{$vmName="Namenode"+$i}
default {$vmName="Datanode"+($i-2)}
}
$vmconfig=New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize
$vmArray1.Add($vmconfig)
```

$i +=1
 } Until ($i -gt $NumberOfVM)
**$vm=Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmconfig -Windows -ComputerName $vmArray1 -Credential $credvm -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate**
But an exception occurs. Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: You should share what exception message you r seeing

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it's your typing error or not. Your `Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem` Command is not inside the loop. That means it will always run only once. Beside of Operating System, you also need to provide Source Image, OS Disk, and Network Interface.

I have written something for you, and I have tested it at my end. It will create a set of VMs in one resource group and one Virtual Network. If you want the VMs in different resource groups or VNet, you can move the creation commands of resource groups or Vnet into the loop.

```
$credvm = Get-Credential
$NumberOfVM = <the number of VM you want to create>;
$ResourceGroupName = "<your resource group name>"
$Location = "East Asia"

## Storage
$StorageName = "<your storage account name>"
$StorageType = "Standard_GRS"



# Resource Group, if resource group has been created comment this out.
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location


## Network
$InterfaceName = "<your interface name>"
$Subnet1Name = "Subnet1"
$VNetName = "<your vnet name>"
$VNetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"
$VNetSubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"

## Compute
$vmSize = "Standard_A2"

# Network
$SubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $Subnet1Name -AddressPrefix $VNetSubnetAddressPrefix
$VNet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AddressPrefix $VNetAddressPrefix -Subnet $SubnetConfig


$i = 1;

Do 
{ 
    $i; 
    $vmName="Namenode"+$i
    $vmconfig=New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize

    $vm=Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmconfig -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $credvm -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate

    $OSDiskName = $vmName + "osDisk"
    # Storage
    $StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageName$i -Type $StorageType -Location $Location
    ## Setup local VM object
    $vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer -Skus 2012-R2-Datacenter -Version "latest"
    $PIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $InterfaceName$i -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
    $Interface = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName$i -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -SubnetId $VNet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $PIp.Id
    $VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $Interface.Id
    $OSDiskUri = $StorageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $OSDiskName + ".vhd"
    $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name $OSDiskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption FromImage

    ## Create the VM in Azure
    New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine
    $i +=1
} 
Until ($i -gt $NumberOfVM)
```